# Iterate over cell versions on BigTable row

Tags: go, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have a row that has multiple versions of a particular cell. **I want to fetch and iterate over all existing versions of this cell**. Something like:

```
for _, cellVersion := range row["ColumnFamily"]["ColumnQualifier"]{
   // (...)
}
```

---

I tried to use the function `ReadRow` but it returns a `map[string][]ReadItem` that is, apparently, a unidimensional cell array.

```
row, err := table.ReadRow(ctx, rowKey)
row["MyColumnFamily"] // -> array of unidimensional cells
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for my question was the fact that the BigTable data model supports multiple versions of each cell. Over-simplistically:  each cell is a multi-dimensional array of different versions of a similar piece of data.

[image: BigTable data model]

The Python SDK implements this concept in a very straightforward way: each cell is represented as a list of items (a list of possible versions).

```
>>> row = table.read_row(ROW_KEY)
>>> data = row.to_dict()
>>> cell = data[<COLUMN_FAMILY:COLUMN_QUALIFIER>]
[<Cell value=b'bla1' timestamp=2020-01-16 21:45:39.921000>, <Cell value=b'bla2' timestamp=2020-01-16 21:57:31>...]
```

In the Golang SDK, however, all versions of all cells are in the same array. Therefore, if you want an array with all versions of the same cell, you have to group it manually.

```
row, _ := r.table.ReadRow(ctx, ROW_KEY)
columns, ok := row[<COLUMN_FAMILY>]

values := make(map[string][]bigtable.ReadItem, 0)

for _, cell := range columns {
    _, ok := values[cell.Column]
    if !ok {
        values[cell.Column] = make([]bigtable.ReadItem, 0)
    }

    values[cell.Column] = append(values[cell.Column], cell)
 }
```

Now we can access a list of different versions of the same cell:

```
cell := values[<COLUMN_FAMILY:COLUMN_QUALIFIER>]
for _, cellVersion := range cell{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fetch the row for a specific column and then iterate over all the results:

```
rowkey := "YOUR_KEY"
row, err := tbl.ReadRow(ctx, rowkey, bigtable.RowFilter(bigtable.ColumnFilter("ColumnQualifier")))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Could not read row with key %s: %v", rowkey, err)
}

printRow(w, row)

func printRow(w io.Writer, row bigtable.Row) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Reading data for %s:\n", row.Key())
    for columnFamily, cols := range row {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Column Family %s\n", columnFamily)
        for _, col := range cols {
            qualifier := col.Column[strings.IndexByte(col.Column, ':')+1:]
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "\t%s: %s @%d\n", qualifier, col.Value, col.Timestamp)
        }
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w)
}
```